# Add a ReadableDuration to a ReadableInstant

Tags: java, jodatime

Given a `ReadableInstant` and a `ReadableDuration`, I want to create another `ReadableInstant` that represents the point in time that lies the given duration after the given point in time. The simplest way to do this that I found is this but I assume there is some way to do this directly:

```
ReadableInstant after(ReadableInstant instant, ReadableDuration duration) {
    return new Instant(instant.getMillis() + duration.getMillis());
}
```

`Instant` defines a method `plus()` which takes a `ReadableDuration` but there are other implementations of `ReadableInstant` so I can't use that method.

Comment: Why not? Just call `toInstant()` and then use `plus()`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Oh, I didn't see that. I'd accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface `ReadableInstant` provides a method `toInstant()` which returns an `Instant`. Call that and then call `plus()` on that `Instant`.

So:

```
ReadableInstant instant;
ReadableDuration duration;
// ...
return instant.toInstant().plus(duration);
```